# converting long to integer without losing the original value

Tags: integer, long-integer, 32-bit, value-type, type-conversion

Is there a way to convert a long value 8769402740 to integer and still maintain the original value . I know about using 
         (int) long 
however it changes the appearance of the number and that is what I would like to maintain.

Comment: Using C#, int means Int32, so 32 bits; long number you're giving us uses 33 bits (hex 2 0AB2 7774) so how can you preserve value? What do you mean with *appearance of the number*?

Comment: Change the base?  Logarithms are cool.

Answer (score 3):

Using C#, int means [Int32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx), so manages 32 bits numbers.
Long number you're giving us uses 33 bits (hex **20AB27774**) so you cannot preserve its value after conversion.
For this reason your number gets truncated within 32 bits and become **0AB27774**.

Answer (score 2):

Considering you're using C# since you did not mention your programming language and platform...

It's not possible.

[`Int32.MaxValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx) value is `2,147,483,647`. This way you cannot accommodate `8,769,402,740` in an int variable.

See [Casting and Type Conversions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx).

> For built-in numeric types, an implicit conversion can be made when the value to be stored can     ***fit*** into the variable without being **truncated or rounded off**.
>      For example, a variable of type long (8 byte
>   integer) can store any value that an int (4 bytes on a 32-bit
>   computer) can store. The inverse is not possible without losing data.

Answer (score 0):

You will need tp give more information that this, for example, which language are you trying to do this in, and on what platform??

An integer changes according to the bit length of the processor being used in most cases.

Also can you explain what you mean by maintain appearance?

An integer on a 32-bit version of windows cannot hold the value 8769402740 as it is too large.

Answer (score 0):

You can "compress" a large number to a smaller number, please see the [Shannon Limit](https://web.archive.org/web/20170911010220/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/65726.html).  However, you'd have to maintain a way to store that data.  What you're asking for is either non-trivial or impossible for the reasons given by Marco.